# How to add action bar to my main activity from another class that extends ActionBarActivity?

Tags: java, android, class, android-actionbar, extends

My problem comes from the fact that `Java` cannot extend two different activities. I have my `main activity` extending `FragmentActivity`. I want to add `ActionBar` with the support to old Android versions. Hence, extending `ActionBarActivity` is needed. How can I use another class which extends `ActionBarActivity` to add the `action bar` in my `main activity`?

Comment: Simply you cannot do that, you can use fragmentactivity or actionbaractivity it's a design problem of compatibility Google library

Comment: simply do as @Alex answer.. :)

Comment: @Alex because I am using fragments in my main activity. I am also supporting older Android versions and hence extending FragmentActivity is a needed. I think I need both.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make your main activity extend [ActionBarActivity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/ActionBarActivity.html)

ActionBar activity itself extends FragmentActivity so you should be fine.